# Vertical alignment of cvline in moderncv?

Tags: vertical-alignment, moderncv

I am currently updating my CV and using the `moderncv` package. When I've updated the 'Languages' section, I've encountered a problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{casual}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 

\firstname{Firstname}
\familyname{Name}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.3\textwidth} % widen first column within CV 

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \section{Languages}
    \cvline{German}{Hallo, mein Name ist Fritz, Ich would like to haben ein Sauerkraut with Schnitzel, bitte. Und dazu ein deutsches Weizenbier. Bitte wo ist der Schlossmuseum? I know a little German, he's sitting over there.}
    \cvline{German Sign Language (DGS)}{Basics}

\end{document}
```

That results in:
[image: Image: result]

So my question is: Is it possible to adjust the vertical alignment of the first respectively of the second column in a `cvline` to middle? I would like that the Basics is in the middle (vertically) of the German Sign Language (DGS). The other case (aligning the left column vertically) is not that important to me.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) answers is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following example I defined a `\ccvitem` command that behaves as `\cvitem`, but with vertical alignment of the columns content (instead of `p{...}` columns, `\ccvitem` uses `m{...}` columns available through the `array` package):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{casual}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage{array}

\firstname{Firstname}
\familyname{Name}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.3\textwidth} % widen second column within CV 

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ccvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}m{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}m{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \section{Languages}
    \cvitem{German}{Hallo, mein Name ist Fritz, Ich would like to haben ein Sauerkraut with Schnitzel, bitte. Und dazu ein deutsches Weizenbier. Bitte wo ist der Schlossmuseum? I know a little German, he's sitting over there.}
    \cvitem{German Sign Language (DGS)}{Basics}
    \ccvitem{German}{Hallo, mein Name ist Fritz, Ich would like to haben ein Sauerkraut with Schnitzel, bitte. Und dazu ein deutsches Weizenbier. Bitte wo ist der Schlossmuseum? I know a little German, he's sitting over there.}
    \ccvitem{German Sign Language (DGS)}{Basics}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, you could use `\cvitem` instead of `\cvline` that appears to be still around just for compatibility with older versions of `moderncv`.